# What is the best custom C# Library for REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, rest

I'm going to write a lot of code that works with SharePoint lists and libraries over REST and C# (HttpClient)

I want to create or find  helper classes that help me do the following tasks over REST:

- Get all list items (preferably in nice C# objects with all SP properties)
- Get item/file by list ID
- Get items using CAML
- Delete item/file by ID
- Update item/file
- Create folder
- Upload a file
- Add List item

Is there a project/library you can recommend I can reuse so that I don't write all these things myself?

**Additional info:**

- CSOM (ClientContext) is not an option
- There are a lot of samples with REST online, but they are too messy
- I did some googling, but could not find one good Library/Project online that does all these things in a way I want
- Preferably, I want this library/project to use HttpClient class

Comment: Re: "There are a lot of samples with REST online, but they are too messy". That's because using the REST API in C# is messy. You have to deal with raw XML or raw JSON. In my opinion you're much better off using the Client Object Model.

Comment: agree, except for the fact that I cannot use CSOM. I have to deal with Xamarin and Windows Phone SDK. you cannot use CSOM with Xamarin. And I cannot aithenticate via CSOM in Wndows Phone apps because of ADFS

Comment: if you can get it working with raw json ( returning specifically ) then the guide made by rob is perfect [link](http://blogs.msmvps.com/windsor/2011/11/04/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-asp-net-asmx-web-service-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I must say it is embarrassing to admit this) I have (partially) done this with REST.

I had used Newtonsoft.Json to parse the responses and HttpWebRequests to interact with the REST API.
(I think you would be able to work with Atom using System.Xml as well.)

However I am not aware of a single library doing the process end-to-end.

Comment: I'm in a long process of creating CSOM-like classes that work via REST. it's actually a lot of fun. Here is an example: Authenticator aithenticator = new Authenticator(Login, password, siteUrl); XContext context = await aithenticator.GetCookiesAndDigest();  XList list = await context.GetList("Photos");  List<XListItem> listItems = await list.GetItems(caml);
 await listItems[0].Delete();

Comment: That does make sense. After all you could then reuse your code in future projects! Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I've uploaded a sample XSOM project [here](https://github.com/Zerg00s/XSOM)

The code will look like so:
[image]

[image]

There are some basic operations available, but it's a good start